# Getting index from 2D array quickly without iteration jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this 2D array as follows:

```
var data = [[1349245800000, 11407.273], [1349247600000, 12651.324],
           [1349249400000, 11995.017], [1349251200000, 11567.533],
           [1349253000000, 11126.858], [1349254800000, 9856.455],
           [1349256600000, 8901.779], [1349258400000, 8270.123],
           [1349260200000, 8081.841], [1349262000000, 7976.148],
           [1349263800000, 7279.652], [1349265600000, 6983.956],
           [1349267400000, 7823.309], [1349269200000, 6256.398],
           [1349271000000, 5487.86], [1349272800000, 5094.47],
           [1349274600000, 4872.403], [1349276400000, 4168.556],
           [1349278200000, 4501.939], [1349280000000, 4150.769],
           [1349281800000, 4061.599], [1349283600000, 3773.741],
           [1349285400000, 3876.534], [1349287200000, 3221.753],
           [1349289000000, 3330.14], [1349290800000, 3147.335],
           [1349292600000, 2767.582], [1349294400000, 2638.549],
           [1349296200000, 2477.312], [1349298000000, 2270.975],
           [1349299800000, 2207.568], [1349301600000, 1972.667],
           [1349303400000, 1788.853], [1349305200000, 1723.891],
           [1349307000000, 1629.002], [1349308800000, 1660.084],
           [1349310600000, 1710.227], [1349312400000, 1708.039],
           [1349314200000, 1683.354], [1349316000000, 2236.317],
           [1349317800000, 2228.405], [1349319600000, 2756.069],
           [1349321400000, 4289.437], [1349323200000, 4548.436],
           [1349325000000, 5225.245], [1349326800000, 6261.156],
           [1349328600000, 8103.636], [1349330400000, 10713.788]]
```

How do I get the index of value 1349247600000 in the array?  I have tried $.inArray(1349247600000, data) but as expected this fails.  Is there any other way or do I have to iterate over each? I am reluctant to add another loop to my process

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical performance versus memory issue. The only way (that I know of) to avoid looping through the array, would be to maintain a second data structure mapping the timestamps to the index of the array (or whatever data might needed).

So you would have

```
var data = [
    [1349245800000, 11407.273], 
    [1349247600000, 12651.324],
    // ...
    [1349330400000, 10713.788]
];

// the timestamps pointing at their respective indices
var map = {
    '1349245800000': 0, // 0
    '1349247600000': 1, // 1
    // ...
    '1349330400000': 42, // n - 1 (the length of the data array minus one)
}
```

This way, you use more memory, but have a constant lookup time when needing the index of the item in the array that a given timestamp belongs to.

To get the index of a given timestamp do:

```
map['1349247600000']; // resulting in 1 (e.g.)
```

If the data structure is dynamically changed, you would of course need to maintain the map data structure, but depending on the context in which you need the lookup, the constant time lookup can potentially be a real time saver compared to a linear time lookup.

Comment: Another user posted an answer and removed it again, but he had a good point: If the number that you need is actually the second element (11407.273 e.g.) in the nested arrays, then the best solution would be to refactor your data structure to an object where the timestamps are the keys and the floats are the values.

Comment: +1 extremely good answer, but you force the Q to make a lot of changes in code, and could by that be better off with 3 lines of loop. Also we dont know the amount of the array - if it is 10000000 your solution is not that good, since it would consume at least 1/3 extra RAM. maybe critical

Comment: Even +1 I dont think this is the answer. It is more a solution to find indexes fast without worrying of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be using an object for this:

```
var data = {
  '1349247600000': 12651.324
}
```

which you can access like:

```
data['1349247600000'];
```

However, this might be a nice solution (IE9 and above) in the meantime:

```
var search = 1349247600000;

function findIndex(data, search) {
  var filter = data.filter(function (el, i) {
    el.unshift(i);
    return el[1] === search;
  });
  return filter[0][0];
}

console.log(findIndex(data, search));
```

Comment: The best answer so far.

Comment: @Arius Notice that `filter` is not supported by IE8 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a different data structure.

Try using a standard javascript object (`{ key: value }` - sometimes called a map or dictionary) to express your data. Looking up keys in an object is highly optimized (using something called hash tables).

If the index in your array has any meaning, store it as a property (typically named `_id`).

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom cross browser solution ?

```
function findIndexBy(a, fn) {
    var i = 0, l = a.length;
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        if (fn(a[i], i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Usage :

```
var list = [[1],[2],[3]], idx;

// idx === 1
idx = findIndexBy(list, function (item, i) {
    return item[0] === 2;
});

// idx === -1
idx = findIndexBy(list, function (item, i) {
    return item[0] === 4;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CLa56/

```
var searchElement = 1349251200000;
var strdata = data.toString();
var newdata = eval("[" + strdata + "]");
var indexsearch = newdata.indexOf(searchElement);
var index = indexsearch/2; // 2 because array.length = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {id: 1349251200000, index: -1};

data.some(function (e, i) {
    if (e[0] === this.id) {
        this.index = i;
        return true;
    }
}, params);

console.log(params.index);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/sDYtb/)

[MDN|some Array Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Note that this solution stops iterating after found, not necessarily over the entire array, so could be much faster for large arrays.